Are Čech complete spaces with no isolated points non-Rothberger?
This is intended to be a self-answering question, which is allowed on StackExchange sites (see here).
The question is inspired by this MSE answer, which shows $\mathbb{R}$ with its standard topology is not Rothberger. Recall that a topological space $X$ is called Rothberger (also known as Property $C''$) if, whenever $\mathcal{U}_n$ is a sequence of open covers of $X$, there exists $V_n \in \mathcal{U}_n$ s.t. $\{V_n\}$ is an open cover of $X$. The linked answer shows $\mathbb{R}$ is not Rothberger by choosing, for each $n$, an open cover $\mathcal{U}_n$ consisting of open sets of Lebesgue measure at most $2^{-n}$. Then if $V_n \in \mathcal{U}_n$ for all $n$, we would have,
$$\lambda\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty V_n\right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(V_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} = 1$$
So $\{V_n\}$ cannot be an open cover of the space. The answer, in essence, only requires the existence of a nonzero nonatomic outer regular Borel measure defined on the space, which one would expect a large amount of spaces to satisfy. In particular,

If $X$ is a (nonempty) Čech complete space with no isolated point, is $X$ non-Rothberger?

Here, we recall that a space $X$ is called Čech complete if it is completely regular Hausdorff and it is a $G_\delta$ subset of its Stone-Čech compactification $\beta X$. It is standard that any complete metric space is Čech complete (see here) and any LCH space is Čech complete (see here).
Note that the "with no isolated point" condition is necessary. Indeed, $\mathbb{N}$ with discrete topology is a complete metric space that is countable and thus easily seen to be Rothberger.

The answer is yes. Indeed, as noted by the question itself and inspired by the answer linked in the question, we have the following lemma:
Lemma: If a $T_1$ topological space $X$ admits a nonzero nonatomic outer regular Borel measure, then $X$ is not Rothberger.
Proof: Let $\mu$ be a nonzero nonatomic outer regular Borel measure on $X$. Choose a sequence of positive numbers $k_n$ s.t. $\sum_n k_n < \mu(X)$. Now, for each $x \in X$, we have $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$. So by outer regularity, there exists an open neighborhood $U_{x,n}$ of $x$ with $\mu(U_{x,n}) \leq k_n$. Let $\mathcal{U}_n = \{U_{x,n}:x\in X\}$, which is an open cover of $X$ for all $n$. Then, if $V_n \in \mathcal{U}_n$, we have,
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty V_n\right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(V_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty k_n < \mu(X)$$
Thus, $\{V_n\}$ is not an open cover of $X$ and $X$ is not Rothberger. $\square$
We now prove the main result.
Theorem: If $X$ is a (nonempty) Čech complete space with no isolated point, then $X$ is not Rothberger.
Proof: By Theorem 3(i) of [1], $X$ admits a nonatomic inner regular (w.r.t. closed sets) Borel probability measure $\mu$. (Note that the first page of [1] mentions all Borel measures considered in the paper are inner regular (w.r.t. closed sets) Borel probability measures.) It is easy to see that an inner regular (w.r.t. closed sets) probability measure is also outer regular, so $\mu$ is outer regular. The result now follows from Lemma. $\square$

This looks plausible to me, but I'll trust the measure theorists out there to check out the finer details. I guess this would in turn mean something slightly stronger: if X contains a nonempty closed copy of a Čech complete space with no isolated point, then it is not Rothberger.

@StevenClontz Yes, or even stronger: if $X$ contains a nonempty closed subset $Y$ s.t. $Y$ has a coarser topology which is Čech complete and without isolated point, then $X$ is not Rothberger.
